# which partition or path only system application can access/read the data in android

Tags: android, filesystems, android-source, selinux

I am working on the customization of the AOSP marshmallow.

I am just trying to understand which partition, only system application can access/read the data and the user application should not access/read data.

I have tried multiple partitions like system, data, .. .Both android user/system application access/read the data or both user/system applications not access/read the data.

May I know which partition or path only system application can access/read the data?

Comment: Are you sure 3rd party applications can access /data directory? As far as I remember, the /data directory is only accessible to 3rd party apps for their own specific directory, they can't access the entire the /data directory

Comment: thanks for your reply @Dan . yes, I have verified. step1.Copied test file in the /data partition step2.Tried to copy the test file into /storage/emulated/0/ and it is copied successfully.

Comment: I'd suggest you to check what ever system you are compiling then, or maybe it was changed in a later android version, I just tried here with Android 10 device ( I have nothing below that) and I can't access neither system nor data directories from my 3rd party app. Are you sure the app that copied the file from /data to /storage/emulated... isn't a system app?

Comment: yes I'm sure,  able to copy test files from /data to /storage/emulated , using 3d party app. I just want to stop that to copy from 3d party app.

Comment: FYI I am working on AOSP M, I have compiled the source code in "user debug" mode.

Comment: If you are in user debug mode, from what I read, if I remember correctly, the device is considered rooted and therefore 3rd party apps can access those directories. Maybe try to build it once with release instead of user debug and then check?

Comment: sure I will check.

Comment: Try /data/system.  adb shell ls /data/system -lZ. Not all system apps can access this directory, only system uid apps

Comment: @YONG I have tried the existing file, it is only accessible only system uid apps. When I have tried with my test file its showing root , root  like ------>  -rw-r--r-- root     root              u:object_r:lge_certificate_file:s0 test_file.